# How can I disable automatic scrolling during mouse down drag select ListViewItems (VB.Net, Windows.Forms)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, mousedown, .net-4.8

When attempting to select multiple `ListViewItem` with drag select, my cursor and scroll bounds will move all the way to the horizontal extents of the `ListView`; which can sometimes be on my second monitor. Is there a way to get stop this from happening? I have tried several different options and the most common method I have seen is to use the snippet below I just can't figure out how to get it to work.

```
Private Sub SubName(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs)
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

---

**Edit**

I just disabled all the methods except for the my methods allowing me to drag/drop files on to the form/controls and tested to see if the issue still occurs. It still is causing my view bounds and cursor to jump to the `ListView` horizontal maximum bounds. Other than MyBase.Load, these are the only other methods enabled:

```
Private Sub ApplicationInterface_DropFiles(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
    Dim Files() As String = e.Data.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.FileDrop)
    Array.Sort(Files, New CompareStringAscending)
    AddArray(Files)
End Sub
Private Sub AddArray(list As String())
    For Each FileName As String In list
        Dim FI As New FileInfo(FileName)
        Dim File_Exists As Boolean = False
        For Each i As ListViewItem In ListViewCollection.Items
            If FI.Name = i.Text Then
                File_Exists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If File_Exists = Then Continue For
        AddFile(FI)
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub AddFile(NewFI As FileInfo)
    If NewFI Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim NewFileName As String = NewFI.Name
    Dim LVISubItems() As String = {NewFileName, NewFI.DirectoryName}
    Dim LVItem As New ListViewItem With {.Text = NewFI.Name}
    LVItem.SubItems.AddRange(LVISubItems)
    ListViewCollection.Items.Add(LVItem)
    LVItem.Checked = True
End Sub
```

I believe this event occurs from within the `ListView` class itself, but I could be horribly wrong.

Comment: Yes I am using windows forms. Most of the forums I read through ended up being for WPF, but I thought I saw one or two that weren't for WPF yet still used that handler. I am probably not remembering correctly, that or the question was misunderstood so a wrong answer was given.

Comment: I do not have any code for dragging/dropping ListViewItems, unless you are referring to drag/drop files onto the form/controls to create new ListViewItems.

Comment: I tested your code (actually, rewrote it: I cannot used that code since you have `Option Strict Off`) and the Horizontal Scroll bar doesn't move. Is this what you were referring to? If not, then describe the issue a bit better. Also, add the .Net version in use.